# Axios não passa dados para API asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, api, react, axios

Procurei por todos os cantos da rede por uma resposta e não encontrei e criei uma aplicação com React que chama uma WebApi Asp.Net core, usando `Axios`. Acontece que os parâmetros não chegam no método da API.

Esse é o chamado com axios:

```
const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'crossdomain': 'true'
  },
};
const params={
  Email: email,
  Password: password
}

await axios
.post(`${URL}?`,JSON.stringify(params), config)      
  .then((resp) => {
    data = resp.data;
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    }        
  });
```

> [image: Esse é o método sendo chamado normalmente mas com os parametros null]

Esse é a classe Startup da API

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se alguém puder ajudar, serei grato.

Obrigado

Comment: passe assim nessa linha: `.post(`${URL}`,params, config) `

Comment: Virgilio Novic.. Segue null os campos na api.

Comment: Só funciona se eu passo na URL 'https://localhost:44318/api/authen/login?Email=teste@email&Password=teste'

Comment: Talvez possa estar configurado alguma coisa errado na API.

Comment: await axios
    .post(`${URL}?email=${email}&password=${password}`)
    .then((resp) => {
        data = resp.data;
      })

Comment: Desta forma funciona

Comment: Não sei se é uma má prattica usar assim

Comment: é mau prática e no controller do asp tem que ser um objeto para dar certo agora que reparei no seu código.

Comment: Mudei para um object e chegou os dados, mas como faço para usar ?
Estão chegando assim: ValueKind = Object : "{"Email":"testeEmail","Password":"testeSenha"}".
Tentei percorrer com Foreach e não deu

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente para que seu código funcione deve seguir da seguinte forma:

1- Crie o modelo em uma classe no [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23):

```
public class Login
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

2 - Crie um método no `controller`:

```
[HttpPost("/login")]
public IActionResult Login (Login login)
{
    //login.Email
    //login.Password
    return Ok(login);
}
```

3 - Configure o [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios):

```
<script>
  function send() {
    const email = 'email@email.com';
    const password = '123456';
    const data = { email, password };
    const url = 'http://localhost:49156/login';
    axios.post(url, data).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
</script>
```

3 - Executar a função `send()`.

e com esses 3 passos tem o cenário de enviar a requisição do verbo `POST` para o `back-end` .NET na classe `Login` que segue o mesmo nome do objeto passado no seu `front-end`.

<sup>***Observação:*** os endereços na variável `const url = 'http://localhost:49156/login'` e na rota `[HttpPost("/login")]` devem ser alterados de acordo com o seu código.</sup>

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo apoio!
Ajudou em 1000%.

Sucesso na tua vida!

Comment: vote na questão como solução do seu problema

Comment: Obrigado.
Feito!!